# How can I add an additional LinearLayout between an existing one and a button?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

Is it possible to show a new `LinearLayout` between an existing one and a button by clicking that button? I want to show a new field to be complete.

This picture illustrates what I mean:

[image: Showing where I want to add the new LinearLayout]

Comment: Yes, it's possible. For example using a [ViewStub](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand)

Answer (score 0):

In the world of programming, anything is possible (I've been told by many developers).
In your code, you simply need to add the following code in the onClick method:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#135517"));
```

Setting background is just an example of what it's capable of achieving. One thing I would recommend you to do is to position it properly to ensure it fits the hierarchy accordingly.
For example:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewToLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.below_id);
```

With this piece of code, you are creating a new params layout and add a rule to the layout which in this example is coded to position below another element.